Dotnet Build Work On Windows But Error On Linux: Unexpected character '�'
On Windows, the project compiles without any issues, but in a Linux container, Ä Ö Ü are not recognized. This results in the following error:
error CS1056: Unexpected character '�'

We found a quick workaround by saving the affected file using the option "Save As" → "Save with Encoding" → UTF-8 with Signature. However, this solution is not ideal, as it would be very time-consuming to do this manually for the entire project.
Of course, we could write a PowerShell script to automate the process, but we are concerned that Visual Studio might ignore certain variables or configurations when running on Linux.
Do you have any suggestions or experience on how to solve this issue effectively and sustainably? What would be the best practice?
What we have tried so far (unsuccessfully):
Using project parameters during build:
dotnet publish "formularserver_NET8_Linux.sln" --no-restore -c Release -o /app/publish -p:TargetFramework=net8.0 -p:CodePage=65001
dotnet publish "formularserver_NET8_Linux.sln" --no-restore -c Release -o /app/publish -p:TargetFramework=net8.0 -p:OutputEncoding=utf-8

Modifications in Directory.Build.props:
xml
Copy code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Set the code page to UTF-8 -->
    <CodePage>65001</CodePage>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Changes in the project file:
xml
Code kopieren
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
    <OutputEncoding>utf-8</OutputEncoding> <!-- Ensures console output uses UTF-8 -->
</PropertyGroup>

Code modification at application start:
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Environment variable for full globalization support:
export DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

Configuration in settings.json for VS Code:
json
"files.encoding": "utf8"

Thank you in advance!

is not ideal quite the opposite. That's the only way you can get rid of codepage-related issues. Otherwise your Linux LC_ENC, or at least your terminal's should match the codepage used to save the file on Windows, eg Latin1. In the latest version of Visual Studio you can finally specify the default encoding and set it to UTF8. In Tools > Options > Environment > Documents. check Save files with the following encoding and select UTF8. Until now, the locale's codepage was used. Which is pretty annoying if you don't live in the US.

You discovered the beauty of windows codepages. You could do this ... IMHO you ought to convince Windows to use UTF-8 on your development machines, in case you want to ship/compile your app for a language other than German.

The problem isn't exactly Windows codepages - Windows is natively Unicode since 1994. The real problem is that Visual Studio uses the user's locale codepage as the default encoding instead of UTF16 (because Windows is Unicode) or UTF8. The codepage is supposed to be used only by non-Unicode applications, and VS is a Unicode application. Frankly, I don't think there are any non-Unicode Windows applications left, except those ported from Linux

Interesting - I haven't used Windows (or MS Development tools) in decades.

@PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your Answer but i can not find
Save files with the following encoding
i am using vs22
could it be somewhere else?
i tried : Tools > Options > Text Editor > General. but not thing there

Oops, it's in the latest Preview version
